# Ruby on Rails: Can you prefix a parameter before the controller name with routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm building a Rails application where I want to prefix a parameter (i.e., a customer code) before the controller name like so:

```
/customer_code/jobs
```

and

```
/customer_code/jobs/new
```

would route to **jobs#index** and **jobs#new** respectively, while the **customer_code** would be used as a variable in the index and new actions.

Any suggestions how I could go about this in the routes.rb file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/:customer_code/jobs
/:customer_code/jobs/new
```

Your link will look something like this /1234/jobs/new, you can then access the customer code in your controller with :

```
params["customer_code"]
```

EDIT:

Try this if you want to use resources :

```
scope '/:customer_code' do
    resources :jobs
end
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I do it using resources :jobs to get all the default routes?